# Scroll to DIV location when rendering a JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, dom

I'm trying to get the browser to automatically scroll to a DIV location when rendering a JSP page.  The DIV can be anywhere on the page and it also has a unique identifier.

I know there is a way to do it using Javascript/jQuery but in my case I want the scroll to occur after the page is loaded.

Basically users clicks on a link, request goes to server and a new page is rendered to browser.  Here is where I want the browser to automatically scroll to the DIV.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use:

```
var scrolltoDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
scrolltoDiv.scrollIntoView(true);
```